# GoogleMap fragment inside fragment containing margin/padding at top?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-maps-v2

Using the "Activity Bottom Navigation" template in Android Studio, I am then adding a GoogleMap fragment inside one of the default fragments.

The main fragment, unchanged from the template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```

The fragment that contains my mapfragment. Only slightly modified from the template's fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.map.MapFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/gmap"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am not including any code in the fragment, because it doesn't matter if there IS code or not - the margin/padding appears at top.

When run, I get the following:

[image: map fragment]

Notice the almost-action-bar madding before the map starts. In the Android Studio designer screen, it **IS** shows that the fragment is taking up

Am I missing some kind of flag or setting or layout quirk to allow the map area to fill up the entire parent (its own) fragment?

Comment: What happens if you delete `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` from the main fragment's top-level `ConstraintLayout` tag?

Comment: @BenP. - Holy f*ck, I'm an idiot. I searched and searched for any padding or margins, and DID see that one, but never tried removing it - thinking it was necessary for the actual action bar. Tested it now, and.. yeah. Curious why they would but that in the template when it's apparently not needed (as the other fragments have that padding as well when I put something at the 'top' of it.)  Make this an answer, and I'll mark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root `ConstraintLayout` on your main fragment is causing the empty space:

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Delete this attribute and the space will disappear.